# How do I add thousand separators with reg ex?

Tags: regex, formatting, replace

I'm using this free [RegExp Designer](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/) which does find and replace. How do I search for all numbers and add thousand separators?

```
Input:      <node num='12345678'>
Output:     <node num='12,345,678'>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To reformat numbers only in "num" attribute values you can do this:

```
(?<=num='\d+)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))
```

But note that this will only work in .NET regexes, which is what RegExp Designer uses.  Most regex flavors only allow lookbehinds that match a fixed number of characters.  Java regexes allow variable-length lookbehinds as long as there's an obvious maximum length, so you can fake it out by using `{min,max}` quantifier an arbitrary number for the maximum:

```
(?<=num='\d{1,20})(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))
```

John Hyland's regex will work in any flavor that supports lookbehinds.

EDIT: I almost forgot; here's how you can do it without lookbehinds:

```
(num='\d{1,3}|\G\d{3})(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))
```

I like this one best for purely aesthetic reasons. :)

EDIT2: I forgot to mention that the replacement string for the last one is `"$1,"`

Comment: My data:   <node num='12345678'> 50000 </node> -- I don't want to convert the 50000 number, only the 12345678 one. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7):

```
s/(?<=\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/,/g
```

That said, if you're working with this data as anything other than strings at some point, whatever language you're working in probably has facilities for formatting numeric output.

Comment: Should I match this expression with my text? It does not work in the RegExp Designer app I mentioned earlier. Could you download it and play around within it to see if it actually does the find & replace?

Comment: @Jeremy, did you try putting `(?<=\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))` in the Regular Expression field and `,` in the Replace Expression field?

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. Much of this goes over my head!

Comment: Just one more thing, how do I let this regex only run for the "num" attribute's value? Because right now it replaces every number it finds!

Comment: That's a very different question. See my answer for that.

Comment: it works! though, a short explanation, like "it will start at the end of the found number (with the negative lookahead at the end), and then subsequently replace packs of three digits..or something"...;_)